# Can't deploy simple node.js app to heroku nor MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, npm

So im trying to deploy a simple twitter like app to HEROKU or MongoDB and i'm currently nailing either. For mongodb I get one out of two outcomes, either a internal server error or the actual code displaying on the browser instead of the app. Since I have two separate folders for each implementation i'm going to post subsequently.

MONGODB

Index.js (This is the server side node code)

```
const express = require('express');
//Cors permite que cualquiera se comunique con el server.
const cors = require('cors');
const monk = require('monk');
const Filter = require('bad-words');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

const filter = new Filter();
const app = express();
const db = monk(process.env.MONGO_URI || 'localhost/meower');
const mews = db.get('mews');

//ORDER MATTERS, WHAT IS FIRST GETS EXECUTED FIRST
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(cors());
//any incoming request that is JSON will pass
app.use(express.json());



//server, when you get a request run this function.
app.get('/',(request,response) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Meower!'
  });
});

app.get('/mews', (req,res) => {
  mews
    .find()
    .then(mews => {
      res.json(mews);
    });
});

function isvalidmew(mew){
  return mew.name && mew.name.toString().trim() !== '' &&
    mew.content && mew.content.toString().trim() !== '';
}

//limit the submit rate

app.use(rateLimit({
  windowMs: 30 * 1000,
  max: 2
}));

//this will wait for incoming data and insert in database
app.post('/mews', (req,res) => {
  if(isvalidmew(req.body)){
    const mew = {
      name: filter.clean(req.body.name.toString()),
      content: filter.clean(req.body.content.toString()),
      created: new Date()
    };

    mews
    .insert(mew)
    .then(createdMew => {
      res.json(createdMew);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(422);
    res.json({
      message:'Hey! Name and Content are required!'
    });
  }
});

//abre el server en el puerto 5000

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:5000');
});
```

Client.js

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const loadingElement = document.querySelector('.loading');
const mewsElement = document.querySelector('.mews');
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/mews';

loadingElement.style.display = '';

console.log('hola')

listallmews();

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  //We grab the stuff from the form
  const name = formData.get('name');
  const content = formData.get('content');
  //We put it in an object
  const mew = {
    name,
    content
  };
  //We send the data to the server
  form.style.display = 'none';
  loadingElement.style.display = '';

  fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(mew),
    headers : {
      'content-type':'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(createdMew => {
      form.reset();
      setTimeout(() => {
        form.style.display = '';
      },30000);
      listallmews();
    });
});

function listallmews(){
  mewsElement.innerHTML = '';
  fetch(API_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(mews => {
      console.log(mews);
      mews.reverse();
      mews.forEach(mew =>{
        const div = document.createElement('div');

        const header = document.createElement('h3');
        header.textContent= mew.name

        const contents = document.createElement('p')
        contents.textContent= mew.content;

        const date = document.createElement('small');
        date.textContent = new Date(mew.created);

        div.appendChild(header);
        div.appendChild(contents);
        div.appendChild(date);

        mewsElement.appendChild(div);
      });
    loadingElement.style.display = 'none'  
    });
}
```

now.json

```
{
  "name": "camitter-api",
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@now/node-server"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/.*", "dest": "index.js" }
  ],
  "env": {
    "MONGO_URI": "@camitter-db"
  }
}
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "CJ R. <cj@null.computer> (https://w3cj.now.sh)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bad-words": "^1.6.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-rate-limit": "^3.1.1",
    "monk": "^6.0.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

And this is the terminal output on implementation. Currently the link shows "internal server error"

```
Alejandro@DESKTOP-LOJH5G7 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Programacion/Meower
$ now secrets add camisite mongodb+srv://alenieto:myactualpassword@camisite-irtu2.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
[1] 444
Alejandro@DESKTOP-LOJH5G7 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Programacion/Meower
$ Now CLI 18.0.0
Success! Secret camisite added under alenieto97 [709ms]        
$ now -e MONGO_URI=@camisite
Now CLI 18.0.0
? Set up and deploy “~\Desktop\Programacion\Meower”? [Y/n] y
? Which scope do you want to deploy to? Alejandro Nieto
? Found project “alenieto97/meower”. Link to it? [Y/n] n
? Link to different existing project? [Y/n] n
? What’s your project’s name? camisite
? In which directory is your code located? ./
No framework detected. Default project settings:
- Build Command: `npm run now-build` or `npm run build`
- Output Directory: `public` if it exists, or `.`
�  Inspect: https://zeit.co/alenieto97/camisite/ei55o9z4q [2s]
✅  Production: https://camisite.now.sh [copied to clipboard] [5s]
�  Deployed to production. Run `now --prod` to overwrite later (https://zeit.ink/2F).
�  To change the domain or build command, go to https://zeit.co/alenieto97/camisite/settings
[1]+  Done                    now secrets add camisite mongodb+srv://alenieto:lapata97@camisite-irtu2.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true

Alejandro@DESKTOP-LOJH5G7 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Programacion/Meower
$ cd server

Alejandro@DESKTOP-LOJH5G7 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Programacion/Meower/server
$ now -e MONGO_URI=@camisite
Now CLI 18.0.0
❗️  The `name` property in now.json is deprecated (https://zeit.ink/5F)
�  Inspect: https://zeit.co/alenieto97/camitter/6b76zrggu [3s]
✅  Preview: https://camitter.alenieto97.now.sh [copied to clipboard] [20s]
�  To deploy to production (camitter.now.sh), run `now --prod`
❗️  Zero-configuration deployments are recommended instead of a `builds` property in `now.json`. The "Build and Development Settings" in your Project will not apply.

Alejandro@DESKTOP-LOJH5G7 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Programacion/Meower/server
```

HEROKU

Here i'm pretty sure im doing something wrong on the index.js or client.js or both. I saw tons of guides and have all the files necesary. When I deploy, the app simply doesn't work. Since I actually tried to adapt the code to work on Heroku I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the code itself. This is The folder:

```
   node_modules
  .gitignore
   index.js
   package_lock.json
   client.js
   favicon.ico
   index.html
   loading.gif
   styles.css
   Procfile
```

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
//Cors permite que cualquiera se comunique con el server.
const cors = require('cors');
const Filter = require('bad-words');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');
const port = process.env.PORT;

const connectionString = 'postgres://gvvsunuvtdhxpq:e9d3239ab17ea6f38d0b6303dee62b7704b37574e5eb2783ca7edb868cc7192a@ec2-18-235-20-228.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d7df9kofqifk5b'
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: connectionString,
})

const filter = new Filter();
const app = express();

//ORDER MATTERS, WHAT IS FIRST GETS EXECUTED FIRST
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(cors());
//any incoming request that is JSON will pass
app.use(express.json());

//server, when you get a request run this function.
app.get('/',(request,response) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Meower!'
  });
});

app.get('/mews', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const client = await pool.connect()
      const result = await client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table');
      const results = { 'results': (result) ? result.rows : null};
      res.render('pages/mews', results );
      client.release();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.send("Error " + err);
    }
  })

function isvalidmew(mew){
  return mew.name && mew.name.toString().trim() !== '' &&
    mew.content && mew.content.toString().trim() !== '';
}

//limit the submit rate

app.use(rateLimit({
  windowMs: 30 * 1000,
  max: 2
}));

//this will wait for incoming data and insert in database
app.post('/mews', (req,res) => {
  if(isvalidmew(req.body)){
    const mew = {
      name: filter.clean(req.body.name.toString()),
      content: filter.clean(req.body.content.toString()),
      created: new Date()
    };

    mews
    .insert(mew)
    .then(createdMew => {
      res.json(createdMew);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(422);
    res.json({
      message:'Hey! Name and Content are required!'
    });
  }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on PORT');
});
```

Client.js

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const loadingElement = document.querySelector('.loading');
const mewsElement = document.querySelector('.mews');
const API_URL = 'https://camisite.herokuapp.com/mews';

loadingElement.style.display = '';


listallmews();

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  //We grab the stuff from the form
  const name = formData.get('name');
  const content = formData.get('content');
  //We put it in an object
  const mew = {
    name,
    content
  };
  //We send the data to the server
  form.style.display = 'none';
  loadingElement.style.display = '';

  fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(mew),
    headers : {
      'content-type':'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(createdMew => {
      form.reset();
      setTimeout(() => {
        form.style.display = '';
      },30000);
      listallmews();
    });
});

function listallmews(){
  mewsElement.innerHTML = '';
  fetch(API_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(mews => {
      console.log(mews);
      mews.reverse();
      mews.forEach(mew =>{
        const div = document.createElement('div');

        const header = document.createElement('h3');
        header.textContent= mew.name

        const contents = document.createElement('p')
        contents.textContent= mew.content;

        const date = document.createElement('small');
        date.textContent = new Date(mew.created);

        div.appendChild(header);
        div.appendChild(contents);
        div.appendChild(date);

        mewsElement.appendChild(div);
      });
    loadingElement.style.display = 'none'  
    });
}
```

Procfile

```
web: node index.js
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "CJ R. <cj@null.computer> (https://w3cj.now.sh)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bad-words": "^1.6.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-rate-limit": "^3.1.1",
    "monk": "^6.0.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "pg": "^7.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

I appreciate a lot any help to deploy on any of the two platforms, im trying to make the most out of this quarantine and have been trying to solve this for twenty hours straight. Cheers to any isolated folks!

Comment: hide your user name and password in dbURL

Comment: Password is changed, anyway there is nothing on the db.

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that you're using `@now/node-server`, try `@now/node` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Change index.js file

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});
```

You can also refer https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: Thats already there, except for the || 3000.  I think the problem is the definition of the database. On the mongoDB code I have a const db variable and I use db.get for the tables. However I cant do that with Heroku, maybe that is my problem?